# Custom Icons in Outlook 2007 Quick Access Toolbar

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, icons, microsoft-office-2007

I'm using `Office 2007` and I have added some commands to the `Quick Access Toolbar`.

Currently I can only assign those commands an Icon from a pre-determined list, I want to put a custom icon. Is that supported?

Just to clarify - this is the area I'm talking about. I want to replace the colored square icons with my own.

[image: Quick Access Toolbar]